# Is there a maximum number of author for a blog?

Tags: author-template, multi-author

I am building a WP blog which will feature the work of many artists and I would like to show, for each post, the artist bio.

Since it is possible for an artist to have many posts over time on the blog, I don't want to insert the bio info directly inside the post and instead use a custom function to show it. This is why I was thinking about using the author meta data to store the info about the artist.

Doing this brings 2 questions:

1. is there a hard limit to the number of authors (or reason not have a lot of authors)
2. is there a reason not to do it this way? (or a better way to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can have as many authors as you'd like.
2. If the artists are not the authors of the blog posts, I would consider using a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) instead, because it would be a more accurate model.

**EDIT**
As it's been pointed out in the comments, taxonomies don't have built-in meta data, and custom post types or users are sometimes easier to handle.

Comment: Taxonomies don't have built-in meta data, custom post types or users are sometimes easier to handle.

Comment: Good point toscho, I'll include it in my answer.